# how to deobfuscate javascript

Tags: javascript, deobfuscation

can any one tell me how to de-obfuscate this?

> `É=-~-~[],ó=-~É,Ë=É<<É,þ=Ë+~[];Ì=(ó-ó)[Û=(''+{})[É+ó]+(''+{})[ó-É]+([].ó+'')[ó-É]+(!!''+'')[ó]+({}+'')[ó+ó]+(!''+'')[ó-É]+(!''+'')[É]+(''+{})[É+ó]+({}+'')[ó+ó]+(''+{})[ó-É]+(!''+'')[ó-É]][Û];Ì(Ì((!''+'')[ó-É]+(!''+'')[ó]+(!''+'')[ó-ó]+(!''+'')[É]+((!''+''))[ó-É]+([].$+'')[ó-É]+'\''+''+'\\'+(...` `Masked for confidentiality reasons`

Comment: It could be anything at all. Do you have any more context...?

Comment: It is obfuscated JavaScript, nothing to do with character encoding.

Comment: ok! and how to de-obfuscate it?

Comment: This is a bad question.

Comment: I wonder which tool does that

Comment: Run this in console it's working

Comment: @RoyiNamir Be careful. Doing so maybe harmful. Some obfuscated scripts loads an iframe that points towards malicious sites.

Comment: @all it's just a challenge on some website; this should be the password to the next level

Comment: This is a challenge from https://www.root-me.org. They explicitly state not to share any solution on the internet. Not really cool mate :/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Look for the "()" in the end. Those are for executing the obscured function code. If you remove the last one and use "toString()" instead in node you will get the following (After formatting a bit):

```
function anonymous() {
   na = prompt('Entrez le mot de passe');
   if(a == 'I changed this to not make it too easy for you' {
      alert('bravo');
   } else {
      alert('fail...');
   }
}
```

Try it yourself, but always be careful, since if you are not careful this kind of code can run harmful stuff on your computer.

PS: A few more words about how it actually works. Those weird french seeming letters everywhere are just variables, which are defined in the beginning. É for example has the value of 2, since using the bitwise not operator on an empty array results a -1, and -~-(-1) = 2. All those backslashes are then used in combination with this numeric variables to get characters which eventually form the code of the function.

Comment: well, this is really old http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/?results=bca1264b0716fad6c7f26b4c1211dc73   and  http://fr.openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/encodage-javascript-83459